# How to solve these type of differential equations: $y''+1/(1+x)y'-(1/(1+x)^2)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any particular way one can go about solving such questions. Here, I assumed $P=1/(x+1)$, $Q=-1/(x+1)^2$ and tried solving it but to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just $z^2y''+zy'-y=0$ where $z=x+1$. Cuacy Euler differential equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Euler-Cauchy DE around the singular point $x=-1$ and can be solved as such making the trial $y=(1+x)^m$.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and answering! How do we know what to take as trial solution? Thanks

Comment: It's the only systematic thing to do for a singular DE. First check if it is a regular singularity, and then if everything cancels nicely to have the form of an Euler-Cauchy DE.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It's just $z^2y''+zy'-y=0$ where $z=x+1$. This is Cauchy-Euler's differential equation.
$$z^2y''+2zy'-zy'-y=0$$
$$(z^2y')'-(zy)'=0$$
$$(z^2y'-zy)'=0$$
Integrate.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome @NatashaJ